# Order by value decrement to one + mysql

Tags: mysql

## Ex : I have V001, V002, V003, V004 records,

```
     tid        is_premium
    ----       ----------
    V001         0
    V002         0
    V003         0 
    V004         1
    V005         1
```

## How to get records order by below like this,

```
      V001
      V004
      V005
      V002
      V003
```

## 2nd Ex : I have V006, V007, V008, V009 records,

```
     tid        is_premium
    ----       ----------
    V006         0
    V007         0
    V008         1 
    V009         0
```

## How to get records order by below like this,

```
      V006
      V008
      V007
      V009
```

I want to above order in MySQL, I have to write but not possible, I tried both multiple column order by using Mysql, but I am not getting correct response. Can anyone help in this., I want to above order in MySQL,

Comment: Why is V001 first but isn't 'premium'?  You haven't provided enough information to us or MYSQL as to how you worked out the required order. Is your sample data correct? i.e. Should V001 be 'premium'?

Comment: What kind of ordering is that? Random?

Comment: added 2nd example, not only V001

Comment: above ex like token management system.

Comment: As long as you don't explain the logic behind the sorting that yo want to apply your question is unclear.

Comment: its a hospital token management system, if one patiant  VIP candidate we can set it as is_premium is true, so first normal patient already in queue, next vip patient, next normal patients so on .....

Comment: Maybe you need to add another column to the table... 'treated_state'? ['waiting' | 'being_treated' | 'completed']. Now you can sort in the required order? clue: V001 is 'being_treated' and the others are 'waiting'. Ignore the 'completed'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what this query does is to sort it in descending order by is_premium and then displays it simply that way

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE ORDER BY `tid`='V001' DESC, `is_premium` DESC;
```

**Note :** Where it says table put your table

**I put a link with the test code for you to try it. :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/57

Comment: No, i want like below order V001, V004, V005, V002, V003, because V004 , V005 is_premium is true.

Comment: So you want to have the fields with "is_premium" True first and then the others? Can you please explain your given order?

Comment: display first record is_premium false, next total records of is_premium true, then last remaing records of is_premium false

Comment: No, V001, V004, V005, V002, V003, i want like this.

Comment: @Chinnu is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, @Chinnu the most efficient way to do what you need is get all from your DB and do some logic in your backend instead use mysql-query. Once you have an object with everything, you can apply conditions that will make sure if some patient is already in the queue and if that patient is premium or not and so on.

```
(SELECT * FROM PATIENTS WHERE `is_serial` = 0 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM PATIENTS ORDER BY `is_serial` = 0 DESC, `is_premium` DESC LIMIT 0, 1000);
```

Test here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/93

[Picture with is_premium=1 first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr28n.png)

[Picture with is_premium=0 first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltOGP.png)

That should resolve your problem **but it will put all is_premium = 1 before the others** keeping the first row intact.

- *For patients with checkup completed too.*

If you want to select only unchecked patients:

```
(SELECT * FROM PATIENTS WHERE `is_serial` = 0 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM PATIENTS WHERE `is_serial` = 0 ORDER BY `is_premium` DESC LIMIT 0, 1000);
```

Comment: @Chinnu let me know if it helps you?!

Comment: displaying purpose it shows correct, but it will take next record as V002, but i want V004

Comment: @Chinnu I did an update in my answer and put a link to let you test, in addition to having an image. I think that is working correctly, can you give a try?

Comment: after completion of first record, i mean patient with token number V001, his checkup completed, next token will be the V004, as per your query it will display V002

Comment: @Chinnu - I understand now. As I say, the best way to approach that could be in the backend with some logic, but if you really need to do that with mysql, could you update your question and most important, could this table have one more column? If so, it will be possible to say to mysql that the patient is 'checked out' or not and compare their tid's.

Comment: @Chinnu - what about now?

Comment: yes, i created one more column is_serial, how do i write condition for that.

Comment: is it possible total query

Comment: @Chinnu, it is! I did an update and you can try with the follow link in the answer and those pictures.